# How to overwrite category page url to some specific cms page url?

Tags: magento2, url, redirect

**How to overwrite category page url to some specific cms page url  ?**

I have category with shop.html
But i want to change or overwrite it on cms page i.e shop-cms.

Even i want to make sure site-map doesn't create the old url in site map.
instead it will be new url which is overwritten.

I tried Marketing->url rewrite but doesn't work.
I'm using magento 2.0.4

Comment: Sorry ,don't understood your question .What i means u want to customise shop.html to shop-cms?

Comment: i want to redirect shop.html to shop-cms  page. where shop.html is category page ,  and shop-cms is a cms page

Comment: try for url rewrite management